# Create row of boxes without overlapping border

Tags: flutter

[Here's what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUowQ.jpg)

I want to create what I have above but the lines that separate the numbers should be the same thickness as the top and bottom borders. My code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
      timeHeader.add(
        new Container(
          height: 35,
          width: 72,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[400],
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.black,
              //width: 2,
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              '${times[i].header_text}',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

I store it as a `List<Widget>` because I am displaying it in a bidirectional scrollable listview (a `ListView` nested inside a `SingleChildScrollView` with the first element of the inside listview as a row, see below)

```
if (index == 0) {
    return Row(
        children: timeHeader,
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right border of the first box is touching the left border of the second box, and so on. As a result, your borders are getting merged. To avoid that, make sure that you have only one border by side.

Use this as your `BoxDecoration`'s border, instead:

```dart
i == times.length - 1
  ? Border.all(color: Colors.black)
  : Border(
      bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
      left: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
      top: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
    )
```